# Run bash script in cronjob

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ubuntu, shell

i'm trying to automate a script using crontab.

I've been searching for some information to help me, but haven't been successful so far.

I created the script with the shebang and full paths.

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date +%H)
wget -O textfile.txt -P /home/server/Desktop/Data (link ending with the date variable)
```

I gave it execution permissions.

```
chmod 700 Script.sh
```

In the crontab, i also specified the full path of both bash (with the 'which bash' command) and the script (with the 'pwd' command), but still nothing.

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/bash /home/server/Desktop/Data/Script.sh
```

I put in every 2 minutes, to see if it works.
Can anyone explain to me why it won't work?

Comment: Which crontab, or how did you add it?

Comment: Is the owner of the cronjob also the owner of the script? If you're running it with `/usr/bin/bash` explicitly it doesn't actually need to be executable - but it does need to be readable

Comment: i used the 'crontab -e' command. How do i check who the owner of the cronjob is?

Comment: If i can check it by doing a 'ls -l' in ```/var/spool/cron``` then the owner is crontab

Comment: `crontab -e` is excellent. Please append `>/tmp/wd_script.log 2>&1` to the end of your cron entry (same line). Wait the two minutes for the line to execute and then paste the results of `cat /tmp/wd_script.log` to your question. If the file doesn't exist then the command hasn't even been attempted by cron.

Comment: You do not need `*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/bash /home/wd-server/Desktop/Weather_data/WD_Script.sh`, only `*/2 * * * * /home/wd-server/Desktop/Weather_data/WD_Script.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `wget -O WD_updated.txt` in the script - that means to put the file in the current directory. What is the current directory for your cron?

do

```
wget -O /home/me/workdir/WD_updated.txt ...
```

or add a `cd` to the beginning of the script

```
cd /home/me/workdir
wget -O WD_updated.txt ...
```

Comment: For a user crontab (including root, but excluding the files in `/etc`) the default is that user's home directory

Comment: @White Owl Thank you! it works! :)